# A pl/sql table will work without having index by binary_ineteger in main code?

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

i am trying to de-bug a code on pl/sql,what's confusing me is, that, the coder hasn't mentioned any indexing method,not even "index by binary_integer",is it ok,how would d pl-engine index the table,if so?

Comment: Please post the code you're trying to debug.

Comment: i would have definately,had i got the rights,but its on client machine and no copy permitted.
i know,its not helping,still,if you can just tell that "table" without indexing method is permitted?
thankx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its perfectly possible. what you are describing is called a nested table. with an "index by" this becomes an associative array (sparse) table.

With a nested table, the index starts from 1 and will increment by one for every element in it.

eg a nested table type:

```
SQL> declare
  2    type mytyp is table of number;
  3    v_t mytyp;
  4  begin
  5    v_t := mytyp (1,2,3,4);
  6    dbms_output.put_line(v_t(1));
  7    dbms_output.put_line(v_t(4));
  8  end;
  9  /
1
4
```

there are other differences in how they can be assigned to as well. Nested tables start with 1 and have to be initialised before you assign to them

eg this fails on a nested table:

```
SQL> declare
  2    type mytyp is table of number;
  3    v_t mytyp;
  4  begin
  5    v_t(1) := 1;
  6  end;
  7  /
declare
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06531: Reference to uninitialized collection
ORA-06512: at line 5
```

as you have to initialise it + extend it to have an element:

```
SQL> declare
  2    type mytyp is table of number;
  3    v_t mytyp;
  4  begin
  5    v_t := mytyp();
  6    v_t.extend;
  7    v_t(1) := 1;
  8  end;
  9  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

if you tried to randomly assign a subscript like you are free to do in an associative array, itr would fail to as nested tables are not sparsely populated:

```
SQL> declare
  2    type mytyp is table of number;
  3    v_t mytyp;
  4  begin
  5    v_t := mytyp();
  6    v_t(2) := 1;
  7  end;
  8  /
declare
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06533: Subscript beyond count
ORA-06512: at line 6
```